# hp-plugin install issue so I cannot scan

Tags: ubuntu, python, printer, hp

running Ubuntu 18.04 and printing well using my HP printer I have an issue with the scan. I can connect to my scanner (using Simple Scan or xsane), however, that's all. Error shows up saying I have install hp-plugin, but during install, it throws an error:

```
error: Python gobject/dbus may be not installed
```

Printer: **HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125a** 
Python ver. is **2.7.15rc1** 
hp-plugin: **hplip-3.19.1-plugin.run** 
hp-doctor: **https://pastebin.com/w488uQV4**

Do you have any advice about what to do?

Comment: 18LTS has specific packages, do not use the HP install.

Comment: So which package should I use?